# I can't find anything resembling a 'Data Structure Selection Guide'

Tags: data-structures

For a subject as popular as Data Structures, its puzzling that there hasn't been a book author, professor, or computer science blogger that has created a sort of 'decision tree', or selection guide which guides you through choosing a data structure for a given problem. Yea the field is huge and yea there may not always be one obvious solution but there are definitely pros and cons of each data structure which can be put together and used to form at least a general selection guide. I've googled this every way I can think of but only found small bits and pieces.

The selection guide should include all of following general data structure groups and thier specifc data structure variants: Arrays, Lists, Binary trees, B-trees, Heaps, Tries, Multiway trees, Space-partitioning trees, Application-specific trees, Hashes, & Graphs.

Does this exist and I just have not been able to find it or is it extremely non-trivial for some reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a pretty good read on some of the major data structures available, this is what i have used in the past. [Data Structures and Algorithms](http://dtkachenko.blogspot.ca/2011/11/data-structures-and-algorithms-when-to.html)

Comment: That page is pretty good. It would be nice to find something more thorough though if it exists..

Comment: I think the next best thing would be to read up on each data structure individually, understand its pros and cons and base your decision off of that information yourself. There are so many variables and differing details from one project to the next that its very difficult to make a guide which satisfies all possibilities.